# Set the array value between any, by key with shifting (without erasure) via php functions

Tags: php, arrays

The question is simple, let's suppose that I have an array like:

```
$array = array(array('bla1' => 'bla1'), array('bla2' => 'bla2'),
    array('bla3' => 'bla3'), array('bla4' => 'bla4'));
```

Yeah it's multi-dimensional so I need to set value between e.g. **array('bla1' => 'bla1')** and **array('bla2' => 'bla2')** without erasure.

I was puzzled to find, through all array_ like functions in php how to do this.

So, as any other programmer would do, I wrote the function:

```
function setArrVal($array, $key, $val) {
  for ($i = count($array) - 1; $i >= $key; $i--) {
    $array[$i + 1] = $array[$i];
  }
  $array[$key] = $val;    
  return $array;
}
```

Works well. 
But still need to do this with php function, is there any way to complete this that way? 
I've tried **array_splice($input, 1, 0, $replacement);** - worthless, it's only working with simple values, not with arrays in array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`array_splice()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php) like so:

```
$array = array(array('bla1' => 'bla1'), array('bla2' => 'bla2'),
    array('bla3' => 'bla3'), array('bla4' => 'bla4'));

$insert = array(array('bla2.5' => 'bla2.5'));

// note the third argument argument is 0
// this will prevent it from overwriting existing values
array_splice($array, 2, 0, $insert ); 

print_r($array);

/* Result */
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [bla1] => bla1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [bla2] => bla2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [bla2.5] => bla2.5
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [bla3] => bla3
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [bla4] => bla4
        )

)
```

#### Demo: http://codepad.org/ivBmZRdn

Is this what you wanted?

Comment: Yeah, thx, I knew about the 3-d parameter should be set to 0, to prevent overriding, but didn't about array(array()); thx again.